# How to send a camera capture frame to YouTube streaming using ffmpeg

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, youtube, streaming

```
import subprocess 
import cv2

# YouTube streaming settings
YOUTUBE_URL = "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/"
KEY = "..."

# OpenCV camera setup
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)

# FFmpeg command for streaming
command = [r"C:\utility\ffmpeg\ffmpeg-2024-02-22-git-76b2bb96b4-full_build\ffmpeg-2024-02-22-git-76b2bb96b4-full_build\bin\ffmpeg.exe",
            '-f', 'rawvideo',
            '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24',
            '-s', '640x480',
            '-i', '-',
            '-ar', '44100',
            '-ac', '2',
            '-acodec', 'pcm_s16le',
            '-f', 's16le',
            '-ac', '2',
            '-i', 'NUL',   
            '-acodec', 'aac',
            '-ab', '128k',
            '-strict', 'experimental',
            '-vcodec', 'h264',
            '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',
            '-g', '50',
            '-vb', '1000k',
            '-profile:v', 'baseline',
            '-preset', 'ultrafast',
            '-r', '30',
            '-f', 'flv', 
            f"{YOUTUBE_URL}/{KEY}",]

# Open a subprocess with FFmpeg
pipe = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

while True:
    # Read a frame from the camera
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break

    # Display the frame
    cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)
    cv2.waitKey(1)  # Wait for 1ms

    # Send the frame through the pipe for streaming
    pipe.stdin.write(frame.tobytes())

    # Check for 'q' key press to stop streaming
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# Release resources
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I'm trying to implement capturing the camera screen using opencv and transmitting this frame to the YouTube streaming broadcast via ffmpeg. YouTube streaming does start when I run this code. However, it appears to be a black screen, not a camera screen. I don't see what the problem is.

I didn't even start streaming at first, but I changed the command option to various things, and when I ran the code, I succeeded in starting streaming. There are many references to transmitting mp4, but there are not many references to transmitting real-time capture. I'm going to process the camera screen using opencv and then send it to streaming. I don't know what the problem is. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I tested on my computer (Mac) with this option and it was pushing to the server perfectly. I didnot add microphone option here.

```
command = ["ffmpeg", "-y", "-f", "rawvideo", "-pixel_format", "bgr24", "-video_size", "640x480", "-framerate", "30", "-i", "-","-c:v","libx264","-c:a","aac", "-f", "flv", f"{YOUTUBE_URL}/{KEY}"]
```

Replace `-pixel_format` with `-pix_fmt` and `ffmpeg` with your `ffmpeg path for windows`. My ffmpeg has libx264 video codec. You can use whatever h264 codec you have.

And don't forget to `pipe.stdin.close()` and `pipe.wait()` before releasing the cap.

Note: Before pushing to the youtube, first try to output it to the file with this option just to test if the video output is perfect.

```
command = ["ffmpeg", "-y", "-f", "rawvideo", "-pixel_format", "bgr24", "-video_size", "640x480", "-framerate", "30", "-i", "-","-c:v","libx264","-c:a","aac", "-f", "mp4", "output.mp4"]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As you told me, I changed the command option and executed it. However, streaming didn't start and stayed on standby. I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: Did you confirm if its saving to a file and file is playing perfectly? I rather debug step by step. First try without the microphone. remove those options related to audio 
'-ar', '44100',
            '-ac', '2',
            '-acodec', 'pcm_s16le',
            '-f', 's16le',
            '-ac', '2',
            '-i', 'NUL',   
            '-acodec', 'aac',
            '-ab', '128k',